# Access Property of object bound to ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have the following MenuItem in WPF:

```
<MenuItem 
    x:Name="Menu1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObject1}" Visibility="{Binding ListOfObject1, Converter={u:NullToVisibleConverter}}"
    >
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter 
                Property="Control.IsEnabled" 
                Value="true"
                />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition 
                            Binding="{Binding PropertyInViewModel, Converter={baseTc:IsNullConverter} }" 
                            Value="true"
                            />
                        <Condition 
                            Binding="{Binding ElementName=Menu1, Path=Items.BoolInObject1}" 
                            Value="True"
                            />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Control.IsEnabled" 
                        Value="False"
                        />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

So i want my MenuItem to be `IsEnabled=false` if the Property `PropertyInViewModel` is null AND the property `BoolInObject1` is true. The DataContext is set to the ViewModel. The object `Object1` is defined elsewhere. So basically my second condition is not working, i.e. i Need to access the property of the item/object from the itemssource to check if this item is enabled or not. 
Can someone please explain me how to do it? So how to define the second condition in order to access the properties of the Objects bound to the ItemsSource.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally, if those are the only conditions, you could add a `Setter` to disable by default, and then add two single-binding DataTriggers: One that enables if `PropertyInViewModel` is not `{x:Null}`, and one that enables if `whatnot.BoolInObject1` is false. Same boolean result that way.

Comment: Its a multidatatrigger not a multibinding, I think there I do not need to have a multi converter, as I have already specified the conditions, do I? The Object1 is a public class, defined in my solution. So of course it's referenced by the ListOfObject1 , I.e. its the type of the list.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. No need for a multiconverter.

Comment: Wait a minute, what's the goal here? This MenuItem is a parent with a number of child menu items, one for each item in `Items`. You want to enable/disable the parent according to some property of the viewmodel, *and* some property of... one of its children? Which child? Or all of them?

Comment: Ok, maybe this is the problem. I want to disable the childs (the itemssources objects) depending on the property. The parent will not be visible if the list is empty. I thought the child would inherit the style, and the parent does not have the boolinobject1 property, but that's probably wrong...

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking. Just a minute while I put an answer together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child menu items won't inherit that `Style`. The way you apply a `Style` to the child menu items is through `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle`, just as with a `ListBox` or `ListView`; all of these classes inherit that property from `ItemsControl` along with the `ItemsSource` property and a few others.

Each child menu item will have one of the `ListOfObject1` items for a `DataContext`, so binding `BoolInObject1` is easy. Binding `PropertyInViewModel` is harder because the viewmodel won't be the `DataContext`. However, it is the `DataContext` of the parent `MenuItem`, which you can get to via the visual tree using `{RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}`.

I've also added a setter for the `Header` property of the child menu items; you'll need to change the property that's bound to, naturally. And I added `TargetType` to your `Style`.

```
<MenuItem 
    x:Name="Menu1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObject1}" 
    Visibility="{Binding ListOfObject1, Converter={u:NullToVisibleConverter}}"
    >
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter 
                Property="IsEnabled" 
                Value="true"
                />
            <Setter 
                Property="Header" 
                Value="{Binding SomePropertyOfItemClass}"
                />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition 
                            Binding="{Binding PropertyInViewModel, Converter={baseTc:IsNullConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" 
                            Value="true"
                            />
                        <Condition 
                            Binding="{Binding BoolInObject1}" 
                            Value="True"
                            />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter 
                        Property="IsEnabled" 
                        Value="False"
                        />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I will check it as soon as possible and mark your answer. Thanks, this took me now ages.

Comment: So this relativesource ancestor, what does it do in detail? Does it set the datacontext to the datacontext of the ancestor?

Comment: @SQLStarter In a word, no. That means instead of going to `DataContext` to look for the property specified by `Path`, it goes off to the ancestor and looks for it there. If it changed the `MenuItem`'s `DataContext` that couldn't work -- you've got two `Binding`s here with two different sources; which would win?

Comment: So it worked. Only i had to use `<Condition "{Binding ElementName=MyWindowName}", Path=PropertyInViewModel}"` instead of the RelativeSource. I guess this is because i stated, that the DataContext is the ViewModel, but probably this is the Windows DataContext. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SQLStarter Are you saying that you made the window its own DataContext? Not a great idea.

Comment: No, i just Set tue datacontext If the window to the viewmodel

Comment: Surprised that binding would work then. But if it works it works. Cheers!